# Expo doesn't run correct

Tags: react-native, expo

I have problems with Expo on Windows 10. When I try to scan the QR it goes to 100% and just stops. I had this problem again but it just got alright after a couple of hours. Now I'm waiting for 3 days.

Comment: Did you `console.log` the code and see if it runs properly?

Comment: When it happened it runs in first moment then I just change something and try again and it goes to 100% and freeze. If there is a problem with the code I expect the red screen with the issue but nothing happens

Comment: 1 week before, it happened again but after couple of hours I wait (I tought it is a problem with the Expo) it just get alright, without doing anything.